# Unable to get posted FormData in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, form-data

I'm trying to use posted FormData form an AJAX call in PHP, but I cannot retrieve the variables. 
What I'm doing wrong?

here is my Javascript

```
var sendData = new FormData();
sendData.append('itemid',$('select#selectItems').val());
sendData.append('itemtitle',$('#item-title').val());
sendData.append('itemtext',$('#item-text').val());

$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.file.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: sendData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

and my PHP

```
$itemid = $_POST['itemid'];
echo $itemid;
```

is always undefined in PHP!

and if I print_r ($_POST);

If I use Firefox the PHP text is:

> Array ( [-----------------------------12850217581176488271638880149 Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "itemid" 99 -----------------------------12850217581176488271638880149 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="itemtitle" The Title -----------------------------12850217581176488271638880149 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="itemtext" The Text -----------------------------12850217581176488271638880149-- )

...and using Chrome the PHP response is:

> Array ( [------WebKitFormBoundarypyFlwBB31gVYXxRP Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "itemid" 99 ------WebKitFormBoundarypyFlwBB31gVYXxRP Content-Disposition: form-data; name="itemtitle" The Title ------WebKitFormBoundarypyFlwBB31gVYXxRP Content-Disposition: form-data; name="itemtext" The Text ------WebKitFormBoundarypyFlwBB31gVYXxRP-- )

thanks

Comment: Could you try plugging in hardcode for select#selectItems and see what happens? IE, put "sendData.append('itemid',('testValue').val());"?

Comment: Are you posting any file input through ajax?

Comment: no, I'm not posting anything else

Comment: @djbhindi yes, but no success

Comment: Try commenting dataType: 'text' ! And let me know if that works !

Comment: @RahulGupta it didn't work

Comment: Refer this link: http://digipiph.com/blog/submitting-multipartform-data-using-jquery-and-ajax

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. When I did not set the Content-Type property(I used javascript), it worked.

The browser then showed(in the Request Header using Chrome debugging):
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarygfXi4NfQAXa8g7PU

and a var_dump($_POST) showed me what I wanted:
array(2) { ["user"]=> string(4) "test" ["pwd"]=> string(7) "testpwd" }

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$.ajax({
.
.
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type","application/json');
    }
.
.
});
```

OR :

```js
$.ajax({
    .
    .
    .
    headers: {"Content-Type","application/json"}
});
```

Comment: Why do you posted a second answer?  You just can edit your old one!

Comment: Yeah i forgot! i will delete the old one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have outdated jQuery.
Check your jQuery version because an important parameter **processData** that you use in ajax request constructor is available from version 1.6.

> As of jQuery 1.6 you can pass false to tell jQuery to not set any content type header.

In order to do it open your browser console and enter:

```
jQuery.fn.jquery
```

I have jQuery 1.4 and this code works for me:

```
var file = $('.rm-action-popup-input[name=file]').attr('files')[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
formData.append('title', params.title);
var xhrForm = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhrForm.open("POST", "/upload.php");
xhrForm.send(formData);
```

Check how your Content-Type header should look like:
[image: right version]

Answer (score 0):

i use  fetch to solve it

```js
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
};
fetch('/API', options).then(function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
    if(resp.ok) {

        resp.json().then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.error) {

            }else{
               console.log(data);
            } // ok
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Respuesta de red OK pero respuesta HTTP no OK');
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Hubo un problema con la petición Fetch:' + error.message);
});
```