# PHP: Post variable is set. Undefined index

Tags: php, post

Having this fragment of php code:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    print_r($_POST);
    if( isset( $_POST['user_token'] ) )
    {
        echo 'ok';
    }
    if( user_token_validity( $_POST['user_token'] ) )
    {
```

The request method is correct. In the POST array, the `user_token` variable is correctly set as POST variable through Postman.

When I call the function `user_token_validity`, this happens:

```
Array
(
    [------WebKitFormBoundarydDwxPLxbqyT4BzAo
    Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "user_token"

    b66df4ca4547679d062e2595953b608b5b38ce42af095abb92b65624e801af35
    ------WebKitFormBoundarydDwxPLxbqyT4BzAo--

)


Notice: Undefined index: user_token in
/public_html/api/getProfileImage.php on line 12
```

As you can see, the variable `user_token` is correctly passed and enhanced too: this is the output from Postman setting as input parameters the token and method POST.

Line 12, is where the function is called.

Comment: What does this `print_r($_POST);` display?

Comment: This:

    Array
(
    [------WebKitFormBoundarydDwxPLxbqyT4BzAo
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "user_token"

b66df4ca4547679d062e2595953b608b5b38ce42af095abb92b65624e801af35
------WebKitFormBoundarydDwxPLxbqyT4BzAo--

)

Comment: I think it would be better if you move the 3rd if statement inside the 2nd if statement, to make sure that `user_token` is set

Comment: If that is what `$_POST` is, then there is no key `user_token`. The key is `------WebKitFormBoundarydDwxPLxbqyT4BzAo Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name` with an equally strange value.

Comment: There are no `user_token` key there only value

Comment: It's really strange: because is set in postman parameters.

Comment: Well there is no question that the content of your $_POST array is really deformed, and does not contain what is should. It should look something like: Array ( [user_token] => b66df4ca4547679d062e2595953b608b5b38ce42af095abb92b65624e801af35 )

Comment: Please, change `print_r` to `var_dump` and post output again.

Comment: The problem is probably in the setup of your postman-request. Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419350/unable-to-get-posted-formdata-in-php

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
print_r($_POST);
if (isset($_POST['user_token'])){
  echo 'ok';
if (user_token_validity(array_column($_POST,'user_token')){
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't resolve the issue, because it doesn't still "see" the variable "user_token"